# Encrypting Web Configuration sections in ASP.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, security

Is there any tools available to encrypt and decrypt Asp.net Web configuration sections like  connection string ,etc.?

Can i get any add-on for this?If i use Enterprise Library i can do so,but without that is there any simple utility available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[aspnet_regiis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx). You can also [do it programatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.protectsection.aspx).